# Show and refresh current date and time in label/textblock

Tags: .net, wpf, datetime, label, textblock

Is it possible to show and refresh the current date and time in a WPF label/textblock?
Maybe some sample code?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: Refer to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490333/updating-a-datetime-to-a-label-in-wpf) ..that's what you looking for probably

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible! My solution (in custom WPF component) is very similar like [this solution](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/dispatchertimer/) only with DependencyProperty, binding and time/date formatting in XAML.

cs:

```
//... 
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Time = DateTime.Now;
}

public DateTime Time
{
    get { return (DateTime)GetValue(TimeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TimeProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Time), typeof(DateTime), typeof(ChannelOverview), new PropertyMetadata(DateTime.Now));
```

xaml:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Time, StringFormat='{}{0:HH:mm}'}"/>
```